# Why I can write to MongoDB P-S-S replicaSet when connecting to two secondary instances?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb P-S-S replicaSet with write concern option set to "majority"

- **p**rimary: **node01**
- **s**econdary: **node02**
- **s**econdary: **node03**

When connect to it using

```
mongodb://test:test@node02:27017/test-db
```

or

```
mongodb://test:test@node03:27017/test-db
```

I can not insert document, resulted in `pymongo.errors.NotPrimaryError: not primary` which is an expected error.

But if I connect to it using

```
mongodb://test:test@node02:27017,node03:27017/test-db
```

I can successfully insert data, and can read back the inserted data from **node01**

I can not understand why I can insert data in this situation. Is this an expected behaviour by design?

Comment: It is generally recommended to specify all the nodes of the replica-set in the [connection URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples) (the docs say "For a replica set, include the `replicaSet` option.").

Comment: What is the output of `db.hello()` and `db.getMongo()`?

Comment: The mongod logs all inbound connections, I think if you check the logs, you will see that the connection actually went to the primary.

Comment: @prasad_ fully correct, however it does not answer the question.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for your advice, I found that when connect to `node02:27017,node03:27017`, `db.hello()` shows that I actually connected to `node01`. It makes sense that I can write because I connected to the primary node. Still don't know why I connected to primary, but I guess that maybe mongodb internal implementation.

Comment: I would rather assume it's the python driver implementation. I tried it with classic mongo shell and there it connects to one of the secondaries.

Comment: I tried with mongosh v1.1.1. So it seems to be a client-side feature.